# Problems adding checkboxes to a listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I'm trying to add a checkbox to a listview layout. I've looked at the various forum  posts  but I'm still having some trouble figuring things out. First, I'm not able to capture the checkbox's clicks.  Secondly, I'm not sure how to map each text box to each dynamic list item. Here's the code (derived from http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html):

WaysToSaveList.java

Here's the waystosave_list.xml file:

WaysToSaveActivity.java file

```
public class WaysToSaveActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText mTitleText;
    private EditText mBodyText;
    private Long mRowId;
    private WaysToSaveDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    private Spinner mCategory;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        mDbHelper = new WaysToSaveDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        setContentView(R.layout.waystosave);
        mCategory = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.category);
        mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.waystosave_edit_summary);
        mBodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.waystosave_edit_description);
        Button confirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.waystosave_edit_button);
        mRowId = null;
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        mRowId = (bundle == null) ? null : (Long) bundle     
        .getSerializable(WaysToSaveDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
        if (extras != null) {
            mRowId = extras.getLong(WaysToSaveDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
        }

        populateFields();

        confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private void populateFields() {
        String strChecked = null;
        Log.v("AppStatus", "Now entering populateFields");
        if (mRowId != null) {
            Cursor todo = mDbHelper.fetchWaysToSave(mRowId);
            startManagingCursor(todo);
            String category = todo.getString(todo  
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(WaysToSaveDbAdapter.KEY_CATEGORY));
        for (int i = 0; i < mCategory.getCount(); i++) {
           String s = (String) mCategory.getItemAtPosition(i);
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(category)) {
                mCategory.setSelection(i);
            }
        }

        mTitleText.setText(todo.getString(todo    
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(WaysToSaveDbAdapter.KEY_SUMMARY)));
        mBodyText.setText(todo.getString(todo
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(WaysToSaveDbAdapter.KEY_DESCRIPTION)));
        }
    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        saveState();
        outState.putSerializable(WaysToSaveDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        saveState();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        populateFields();
    }

    private void saveState() {
        String category = (String) mCategory.getSelectedItem();
        String summary = mTitleText.getText().toString();
        String description = mBodyText.getText().toString();
        String checked = "-1";
        if (mRowId == null) {
            long id = mDbHelper.createWaysToSave(category, summary, description,   
            checked);
            if (id > 0) {
                mRowId = id;
        }
    }
```

Waystosave_row.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/icon" 
    android:src="@drawable/addwaytosave"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4px" 
    android:layout_marginRight="8px"
    android:layout_height="40px" 
    android:layout_marginTop="8px"
    android:layout_width="30px">
</ImageView>

<TextView 
    android:text="@+id/TextView01" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="20px" 
    android:layout_marginTop="6px" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:textColor="@color/black">
</TextView>

<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/check" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
</CheckBox>

</LinearLayout>
```

waystosave_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout style="@style/TitleBar">
        <ImageButton style="@style/TitleBarAction"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_home"
            android:src="@drawable/title_home"
            android:onClick="onClickHome" />
        <ImageView style="@style/TitleBarSeparator" />
        <TextView style="@style/TitleBarText" />
        <ImageButton style="@style/TitleBarAction"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_about"
            android:src="@drawable/about"
            android:onClick="onClickAbout" /> 
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="14px"
        android:text="What are ways you save energy? Press the 'Menu' button to insert 
        your tip." /> 
    <ListView 
        android:id="@android:id/list" 
        android:textSize="18px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@android:id/empty" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="18px"
        android:text="@string/no_waystosave" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

WaysToSaveDbAdapter.java file

```
public class WaysToSaveDbAdapter {
    // Database fields
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_CATEGORY = "category";
public static final String KEY_SUMMARY = "summary";
public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static final String KEY_CHECKED = "checked";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "todo";
private Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private WaysToSaveDbHelper dbHelper;

public WaysToSaveDbAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

// http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

public WaysToSaveDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    dbHelper = new WaysToSaveDbHelper(context);
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}

public long createWaysToSave(String category, String summary, String description, 
    String checked) {
    ContentValues initialValues = createContentValues(category, summary,
    description, checked);
        return database.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

public boolean updateWaysToSave(long rowId, String category, String summary,
String description, String checked) {
    ContentValues updateValues = createContentValues(category, summary,
    description, checked);
    return database.update(DATABASE_TABLE, updateValues, KEY_ROWID + "="
    + rowId, null) > 0;
}

public boolean deleteWaysToSave(long rowId) {
    return database.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

public Cursor fetchAllWaysToSave() {
    return database.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
    KEY_CATEGORY, KEY_SUMMARY, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_CHECKED }, null, null, null,
    null, null);
}

public Cursor fetchWaysToSave(long rowId) throws SQLException {
Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
KEY_ROWID, KEY_CATEGORY, KEY_SUMMARY, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_CHECKED },
KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }

        return mCursor;
}

private ContentValues createContentValues(String category, String summary, String 
    description, String checked) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_CATEGORY, category);
    values.put(KEY_SUMMARY, summary);
    values.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, description);
    values.put(KEY_CHECKED, checked);
    return values;
}
}
```

WaysToSaveDbHelper.java files

```
public class WaysToSaveDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "applicationdata";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database creation sql statement
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table todo (_id integer   
    primary key autoincrement, " + "category text not null, summary text not null,  
    description text not null, checked text not null);";

public WaysToSaveDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,
int newVersion) {
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS todo");
    onCreate(database);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're basically going to have to make your own list adapter. Since you're using a cursor, you'll want to sublcass the [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) class. In your bindView method you'll do things like this:

```
public abstract void bindView (View view, Context context, Cursor cursor){

  //assign onClick listener to the checkbox
  CheckBox checkBox = (Checkbox)view.findViewById(R.id.check);
  //assign an onClickListener to the checkbox
  checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view){
      //do what ever you want here
    }
  });

  TextView label = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.label);
  //assign whatever lable you want. remeber, you have the cursor pointing
  //to what this row is supposed to be displaying.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I wasn't able to get this to work and I'm looking at other implementation options instead. The application crashed when I attempted to use my custom adapter.

Comment: I edited my answer. Not sure if it will help, but the change should make things different and better now if you could get it working.